# Why isn't ddd displaying the source code?

Tags: c, gdb, ddd-debugger

When I run my ddd, it doesn't display the source code. The source window is blank. The execution is still there for example I can step through the program but there is no visual indication where in the code the execution is happening.

How can I fix this?

I run it using this command in xterm:

```
ddd mycode
```

Also is there any other debugger like ddd for Mac OS X? If so, could you please give me step by step instructions about how to download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check whether the program has been compiled with debugging information.

For example, if you're using g++ you should include the -g option.